# Android - Getting results of a certain language in google map autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a custom autocomplete edittext using google map API but in some predictions I get half English and half my language. Is there any way to getting predictions of my language? thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Sounds like this feature request in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150